# how to load image properly by using firebase storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm trying to load images from Firebase Storage.
I'm using this library
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_image

I used futurebuilder to get lists data from Firebase Realtime Database. and get image url by fetcted data.

But It seems Firbase Image library is trying to load data before fetching data. so I can read this error.
When I put url as string manually, it show well.

***PlatformException(firebase_storage, com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: Object does not exist at location., {code: object-not-found, message: No object exists at the desired reference.}, null)***

Code is here

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_image/firebase_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart';

class ServiceDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ServiceDetailPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("services");
  List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> lists = [];
  int serviceIndex = Get.arguments['index'];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: dbRef.once(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                lists.clear();
                Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data!.value;
                values.forEach((key, values) {
                        lists.add(values);
                  }
                );
                return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: lists.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Padding(
                              AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: 1.0,
                                child: Image(
                                  image: FirebaseImage('gs://xxx.appspot.com/images/' + lists[index]["uid"] +'.jpg',
                                      shouldCache: true, // The image should be cached (default: True)
                                      maxSizeBytes: 3000 * 1000, // 3MB max file size (default: 2.5MB)
                                      cacheRefreshStrategy:
                                      CacheRefreshStrategy.NEVER // Switch off update checking
                                  ),
                                  width: 100,
                                )
                              ),
                    );
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you print this value `lists[index]["uid"]`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes, it was right value

Comment: @PeterHaddad I review all the data. you are right! Thanks. Have a nice day.